# Woocommerce webhooks data transfer

Tags: rest, woocommerce, routes, webhooks

I am using woocommerce webhooks to send an order to an external software.
So what I did was to create the webhook and create a wordpress rest route to get the order data and then use CURL to send the order data to the custom software.

Everything works but I cannot get the order Object.

Can someone help?

Here the route Registration:

```
register_rest_route( 'test/v1', '/order/send/', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'send_order',
));
```

Here the callback function:

```
function send_order(WP_REST_Request $request){
    $fp = fopen(dirname( __DIR__ ).'/test-orders.txt', 'w');
    $json = json_encode($request);

    if(fwrite($fp, $json)){
        fclose($fp);
        $return['order']['code'] = 200;
        $return['order']['message'] = "OK";
        $return['order']['data'] = $json;
    }

    return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

Here the correct callback function:

```
function send_order(WP_REST_Request $request){
    $fp = fopen(dirname( __DIR__ ).'/test-orders.txt', 'w');
    $json = json_encode($request->get_params();

    if(fwrite($fp, $json)){
        fclose($fp);
        $return['order']['code'] = 200;
        $return['order']['message'] = "OK";
        $return['order']['data'] = $json;
    }

    return $return;
}
```